# Python linear programming - how to constrain a variable to be an integer

Tags: python, constraints, pulp

I would like to maximize the probability of winning a raffle by buying a certain number of tickets. For this, I wrote the following code

```
import numpy as np
import math as mt
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from pulp import *

def objective(tickets, winners = 500, losers = 2500, cost_of_ticket = 40, winning_amt = 1000):

    Pwin = 1 - mt.factorial(losers)//mt.factorial(losers - tickets)*mt.factorial(winners+losers-tickets)/mt.factorial(winners+losers)
    Ewin = Pwin*(winning_amt - cost_of_ticket*tickets)

    return Ewin


# declare your variables
tickets = LpVariable("tickets", range(0, 10))   # 0<= tickets <= 10

prob = LpProblem("problem", LpMaximize)

#define the objective
prob += objective(tickets)

# solve the problem
status = prob.solve(GLPK(msg=0))
LpStatus[status]

# print the results
value(tickets)
```

The issue seems to be that the number of tickets that get passed into the objective function is not an integer (and the factorial function then fails). Can anyone suggest how I should ensure that the ticket is restricted to positive integer values?

The answer, for checking, should be 8. I can do this by manually calling the objective function and checking.

Comment: Well, the obvious way is to transform it to an integer by calling `int()` on the value.  Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to this - but where should I make it an integer? In the objective function or when I declare "tickets" as an LpVariable?

Comment: You need to declare it when defining the variable like explained [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/pulp.html#pulp.LpVariable). On top of that i'm really not sure if your function-based approach will work here, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: If `tickets` is an object of type `LpVariable` how can you do something like: `losers - tickets` what's the meaning of an integer minus an object ?

Comment: I see - I haven't used scipy either but I would like to retain the ability to keep the objective as a function and modify it as I need. Could you suggest a general way to proceed to maximize such a function?

Comment: Okay... tried the code and it's like i expected. You are missing more or less the core-idea of LPs. There is some kind of standard-form or some wrapped-form like used in pulp, based on affine-expressions. This means: those variables are some kind of objects internally and you never can use them in some function like that expecting native types!

Comment: There is no general way per se. You will have to play by the rules of the modelling system. Look up how a pulp-expression is build and implement a function creating an affine expression based on parameters / variables which are arguments. Remark: it's unlikely that you can express this as LP, but i won't analyze it in detail.

Comment: Linear programming is in P, integer linear problem is in NP. Even if you can syntactically enforce integers, your algorithms won't work the same way. You will need to use an ILP solver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objective is really

```
 ExpWin(t) = choose(N,t)*(A-C*t)
```

where t is an integer variable and N,A,C are constants. This is a nonlinear function so a linear MIP solver will not be able to handle this.

For this problem it is silly, but in general we can linearize this. Introduce binary variables x(i) with:

```
x(i) = 1 if tickets=i
       0 otherwise
```

This can be enforced by

```
sum(i,x(i)) = 1
sum(i,i*x(i)) = tickets
```

This only makes sense if the range of variable tickets is small (in your case 10). Now we can precalculate a constant array w(i) which is the expected win if the number of tickets is i. Now the objective can look like:

```
max sum(i, w(i)*x(i))
```

which is now linear.

Anyway it is always a good idea to step away from code and write down the problem in math. This can help you think about the problem in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict a variable to integers when you define it:

`tickets = LpVariable("tickets", range(0, 10), cat='Integer')   # 0<= tickets <= 10`

As per sascha's comment, this is explained [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/pulp.html#pulp.LpVariable)